# How to select multiple photos from gallery using jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In my project i want to display the paths of gallery photos using lazy column in jetpack compose but when i select any photos and return back to screen , lazy column dost not show any paths. This my code

```
  @Composable
fun ItemScreen(){
  Column(modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxSize()
    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    .padding(10.dp)) {
      Headline(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth())
      AddItemRow(titleName = "Enter Color", KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text))
      OpenGallery()
}

 @Composable
fun OpenGallery(){
  var selectedImage =  remember { mutableStateListOf<Uri?>() }
  val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = ActivityResultContracts.GetMultipleContents()){
    selectedImage = it.toMutableStateList()
  }
  GalleryContent(selectedImage) {
    launcher.launch("image/jpeg")
  }
}

 @Composable
fun GalleryContent(
selectedImage: MutableList<Uri?> ?= null,
OnImageClick: () -> Unit
)
{
 if (selectedImage?.isEmpty() == true) {
    Button(
        onClick = OnImageClick,
    ) {
        Text(text = "Choose Photos", color = Color.White, style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall)
    }
}
 else{
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.height(300.dp)) {
        items(selectedImage!!){ it ->
            Text(text = it?.path.toString(), color = Color.Black)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(9.dp))
        }
    }
 }
}
```

How do i fix it . Please help

Comment: checkout this article https://www.howtodoandroid.com/pick-image-from-gallery-jetpack-compose/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `selectedImage = it.toMutableStateList()` you can use:

```
val selectedImage = remember { mutableStateListOf<Uri?>(null) }
val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetMultipleContents()) {
    selectedImage.apply {
        clear()
        addAll(it)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it working. But I ain't getting why "selectedImage = it.toMutableStateList()" this code is not working..

Comment: check the definition of `toMutableStateList()` : `fun <T> Collection<T>.toMutableStateList() = SnapshotStateList<T>().also { it.addAll(this) }`. You are using `also`. Instead in the code reported in the answer you are adding the items in the `selectedImage` instance (`this`)

Comment: How to restrict the selection count